# Stuck on how to make my scoring system work

Tags: c#, game-engine

So I am making a guess the word game in a windows form program in C#, and one of the requirements are that I must include a scoring system. (start out with 100 points, each time a wrong letter is guessed 10 points are subtracted from the total 100 and if you guess right it adds 10 to the total 100.) I have everything else working except for the points. I could really use some help as to how to fix this problem. Mind taking a look?`

```
public void CheckLetter(string word)
        {
            lblWord.Text = "";
            corLetter += word[0];

        score = score;
        int amountToUpdate = 0;
        score = score + amountToUpdate;
        for (int i = 0; i < mysteryWord.Length; i++)
        {
            count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < corLetter.Length; j++)
            {

                if (corLetter[j]== mysteryWord[i])
                {
                    lblWord.Text += corLetter[j].ToString().ToUpper();
                    count++;
                }              
            }

           if (count == 0)
                {
                    lblWord.Text += "_ ";
                }
        }
        bool letterInWord = false;


        for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
        {
            if (rtbGuess.Text == mysteryWord[i].ToString())
            {
                letterInWord = true;
            }
        }
        score = score + amountToUpdate;
        lblPoints.Text = (score).ToString();
        if (!letterInWord) 
        {
            lblPoints.Text = (score = score - 10).ToString();
        }
    }`
```

Comment: Please don't make us do too much hard work. You haven't explained your variables very well. Some are kind of obvious, but some aren't. This shouldn't be a system archeology exercise.

Comment: What is the problem you are having? What is not working exactly?

Answer (score 2):

What exactly isn't working about the score? I just wrote some code up real quick, and had the score working fine. I see lots of things in your code I don't understand though, like:

```
score = score;
int amountToUpdate = 0;
score = score + amountToUpdate;
```

at the beginning, and:

```
score = score + amountToUpdate;
lblPoints.Text = (score).ToString();
```

at the end. Some of your variable names help, like rtbGuess tell me the guesses are typed into a rich text box.

Anyway, your code checks if the letter is incorrect, but not if it IS correct:

```
if (!letterInWord)
{
    lblScore.Text = (int.Parse(lblScore.Text) - 10).ToString();
}
else
{
    lblScore.Text = (int.Parse(lblScore.Text) + 10).ToString();
}
```